# Save multi-line text from textarea

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a form which contains a `<textarea>....</textarea>` field. after saving the text it shows the result in another form but in paragraph `<p>...</p>`

the problem is it shows all lines connected together as one line

when I go to edit field, the line are presented correctly (multi-lines)

how to show all line as entered in `<textarea>....</textarea>`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this problem-

1. **Using `<br>` tags**

   You need to convert your new lines to `<br>` tags while displaying the data in your paragraph `<p>`. Something on the following lines will help-

   ```
   var value = $('.textareaClass').val();
   $('.paragraphClass').html('<p>'+(value.replace(/\r?\n/g,'<br/>'))+'</p>');
   ```
2. **Using CSS rules**

   Another simpler way to do this is by using CSS, in which, you simply have to add the rule `white-space: pre-wrap` to your `<p>` class. For example, if your paragraph has class `text-content` then you simply have to do-

   ```
   .text-content {
       white-space: pre-wrap;
   }
   ```

   DEMO: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t90trxn8/)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace newline with **[`<br>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br)** to provide new line in html

```js
$('#text').on('input', function() {
  $('#res').html(this.value.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br>'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id=text></textarea>
<div id=res></div>
```

---

Or you need to wrap each string after newline in `p` tag

```js
$('#text').on('input', function() {
  $('#res').html('<pr>' + this.value.split(/\r?\n/).join('</p><p>') + '</p>');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id=text></textarea>
<div id=res></div>
```

Comment: @AbdallahSabri : glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `<pre>` instead of `<p>` and let it with the same width of the `<textarea>`. Additional parameters were added to copy the wrap and scroll behaviors aswell:

```js
function test(){
var thetarget = document.getElementById("b");  
thetarget.innerHTML = document.getElementById("a").value;
thetarget.scrollTop = thetarget.scrollHeight;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: lavender;  
}

textarea, pre {  
  width: 200px;
  height: 176px;
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
  white-space: -pre-wrap;
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<textarea id=a oninput="test()"></textarea><pre id=b></pre>
```